# Testing all possible combinations of a group that sum to 100%

Tags: python

Say I have 6 variables that are used in a calculation to produce a number.

I would like to test all possible weightings of the variables to find the combination that produces the lowest number in the calculation.

e.g A 10%
B 20%
C 15%
D 05%
E 30%
F 20%

Can someone point me in the correct direction of how to research this? Are there existing algorithms that I can look into? My initial thoughts were to iterate using nest for loops stepping 0.01% at a time, but I believe this would result in an absurd number of iterations.

Comment: See [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) and example on the bottom of the page. However it's not guaranteed to traverse *all* the combinations. It will fall into a local minimum, not necessarily global minimum. You need, however, to give it an initial point from where you'll start optimization. You can try running the algorithm say 1000 times with random initial point, and select the best solution

Comment: You have to limit the infinite variations first e.g. only using `int`. Furthermore you coud reduce the intervall of variations further by taking the smallest increment into account. Assuming 1% is the smallest weight than you do not have to consider 95%-100%.

Comment: Could you share the function you use for the calculation? If it is unknown, you could still try some optimization like gradient descent. Again, the results would depend on whether your function is "well behaved" or not.